# Endpoints with oAuth: get the current ClientId

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I just started to build with Endpoints in Google App Engine and everything seems to be working just fine. My API is rejecting non-whitelisted Client Ids and allowing the few I whitelisted.

The one thing I currently can't seem to get working though is getting the Client ID that's calling my Endpoint.

It seems trivial, but I can't seem to find out where to look.

Comment: I don't think that is possible when you use @Api clientId whitelisting. You basically abstract away all the oauth2 stuff, so there is no point in supplying you the clientId. May i ask what you need the clientId for? You could always create different API-Methods that whitelist different clientIds and thus make sure what the client id is.

Comment: I'll be using Endpoints as an API to my Android app, and I figured that looking for the ClientId would be the simplest way to find out if it's my Debug, Alpha, Beta or Release version that's making the call. But you're probably right, when using whitelisting one is not supposed to check for client id.

Answer (score 0):

In the python libraries, the client id is part of the user object. You may be able to get the same information from the `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` instance that the endpoint authentication returns.

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/code_walkthrough#oauth_protecting_a_method

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you mention that what you really want is to determine what version of your app you're currently in. For this or similar purposes all my app engine project share a small Util class containing something like this:

```
/**
 * Whether this is a development server or production environment
 */
public static final boolean DEBUG = (SystemProperty.environment.value() != SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production);

/**
 * AppId this application is running under (works in production environment)
 */
public static final String APP_ID = SystemProperty.applicationId.get();

/**
 * The mail domain for this application
 */
public static final String MAIL_DOMAIN = AppengineEnv.APP_ID + ".appspotmail.com";
```

To check for local debug i can then check the DEBUG constant of this class. To check what release you're on you can analyze the APP_ID constant by using a consistent naming schema in your GAE app id, like "myappid_beta", "myappid_alpha", etc.

Well that is all unless i got it totally backwards and what you want is not the version of your app engine app instance but the version of the android application. If you want that i would suggest to simply add a field in your requests containing the application version.

Another idea would be to use different versions for your endpoint classes. When doing so you can put your actual code into a business logic class and make your endpoint classes just stubs that call that logic including the version, which you could set as a constant in your endpoints class. This could look similar tho this:

```
class BusinessLogic {
    public static void doAwesomeStuff(String version, ManyMoreParams){ ... }
}

@Api (
    version = "beta",
    ...
)
class BetaEndpoints {
   private static final String VERSION = "beta",
   @ApiMethod( ... )
   public void doStuff(){
      BusinessLogic.doAwesomeStuff(VERSION, moreparams);
   }
}

@Api (
    version = "alpha",
    ...
)
class BetaEndpoints {
   private static final String VERSION = "alpha",
   @ApiMethod( ... )
   public void doStuff(){
      BusinessLogic.doAwesomeStuff(VERSION, moreparams);
   }
}
```